# I need to create a function in R for mean without using the base functions mean() or sum()

Tags: r

I know this is a pretty simple question but I am new to R and am having serious trouble coming up with a mean function that does not include "sum()". Can anyone help with this? Here is what I have:

```
newmean <- function(x)
  {mn = sum(x)/length(x)}
simple <- c(1:9)
print(newmean(simple))
```

But I have to replace the "sum()" with something else. What should I do?

Comment: Can you use a loop to count your values of x?

Comment: I think that would be ok? The instructions for this question are unfortunately too vague, but I don't see why not.

Answer (score 4):

A very basic approach:

```r
newmean <- function(x) {
  sum_ <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    sum_ <- sum_ + x[i] 
  }
  sum_ / length(x)
}

newmean(1:10)
5.5
```

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
newmean <- function(x) Reduce(`+`, x)/length(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `crossprod` + `rep` like below

```
newmean <- function(x) c(crossprod(x,rep(1,length(x)))/length(x))
```

and you will see

```
> newmean(seq(10))
[1] 5.5
```